# Average degree of neighbors in a simple graph (-> Friendship paradox)

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and $v\in V$ we set $N(v) = \{w\in V:\{v,w\} \in E\}$ and $\text{deg}(v) = |N(v)|$.

The *average degree of the neighbors* of a vertex $v$, or $\text{ad}(v)$, is the average of $\{(deg(x):x\in N(v)\}$.

The [Friendship Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_paradox) states that in many graphs, the share of vertices $v$ with $\text{deg}(v) < \text{ad}(v)$ is more than $50\%$. Of course, there are trivial counterexamples: in the complete graph $K_n$, this share is $0$. So it appears interesting to consider the share of "popular vertices": We call a vertex $v$ *popular* if $\text{deg}(v) > \text{ad}(v)$.

Question: Can the share of popular vertices be arbitrarily close to 1 in finite graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question is Yes.

Consider the complete graph on $n$ vertices with *one edge removed*. It is easy to see that the 2 vertices adjacent to the sole edge that was removed are the only ones that are not popular. So the share of popular vertices is $\frac{n-2}{n}$, which converges to $1$ as $n$ grows large.

Comment: Or take a union of lots and lots of copies of an n-regular graph, and a single m-regular graph, where m<n. As you take more and more copies of the n-regular graph, the vertices of above-average degree n are a larger and larger proportion of all the vertices.