# Degree of neighbors in a simple graph (friendship paradox variant)

Tags: graph-theory

*Context: this question is a translation of a common informal phrasing of the friendship paradox ("Most people have fewer friends than most of their friends"). Note that the question is similar to, but distinct from, [Average degree of neighbors in a simple graph (-> Friendship paradox)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205848/average-degree-of-neighbors-in-a-simple-graph-friendship-paradox).*

Given a simple graph $G=(V,E)$ define:

- $\mathrm{N}(v) = \{w\in V:\{v,w\} \in E\}$, the neighbors of a vertex.
- $\mathrm{deg}(v) = |\mathrm{N}(v)|$, the degree of a vertex.
- $\mathrm{pop}(v) = |\{w \in \mathrm{N}(v) : \text{deg}(v) > \text{deg}(w)\}|$, the popularity of a vertex (*i.e. the number of neighbors with lower degree*).

A vertex is said to be **popular** iff $\mathrm{pop}(v) > \frac{\mathrm{deg(v)}}2$: i.e. *the vertex has higher degree than most of its neighbors*. **Are there any graphs where more than half of the vertices are popular?** Note that the counterexamples given in [Average degree of neighbors in a simple graph (-> Friendship paradox)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205848/average-degree-of-neighbors-in-a-simple-graph-friendship-paradox) do not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a modification of the previous example works. Take some number $n$ such that there are proper divisors $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n+1$ with $a>b$. Let $V=V_1\sqcup V_2$, with $|V_1|=n$, $|V_2|=n+1$. Take $n/a$ disjoint copies of $K_a$ on $V_1$, and $(n+1)/b$ disjoint copies of $K_b$ on $V_2$. Finally, take the *antigraph* of the union of these cliques.

Then each $v\in V_2$ has degree $2n+1-b$; it has $n+1-b$ neighbors of the same degree, and $n>n+1-b$ neighbors of degree $2n+1-a<2n+1-b$, so $v$ is popular.

A similar method works if we need $\mathop{\rm pop}(v)>(1-\epsilon)\deg(v)$ for at least half of the vertices.